# How to can I get all special character, where is not SPACE, using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

When I use `\W` in `Regex`, it will get all special character, but I wan not get Space.

How to can I get all special character using Regex, where it is not Space, in `javascript`?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "special character"? [Regexp meta character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions) or any character except letters, digits and whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negated character class instead:

```
[^\w\s]
```

This will match a character that is not a word character and not a white-space.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV7fE5/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `[^\s\w]` which will return all characters that are not space nor letters

**[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cU5eG8/1)**